# Angular controller inherit variable without $scope

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, controller

I'm trying to follow John Papa's guidelines, in which he explains how using `this` combined with `controllerAs` is preferable to `$scope`.

The problem is that I can't find an easy way to get a variable (`user`) defined in ParentController (`vm.user`) and use it, even transform it in a ChildController.

Code for illustration :

`controllers.js`

```
 app.controller('ParentController', function() {
     var vm = this;
     vm.user = {firstName:"John", lastName:"doe"};
 });

app.controller('ChildController', function() {
     var vm = this;
     /* How can I access 'vm.user' defined in ParentController
        without using $scope as John Papa's suggests ? */
 });
```

`index.html`

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
</div>
```

I could just put everything in one big controller but I want to keep my code clean and readable.

Thanks!

Comment: Some code would help to understand what's your problem.

Comment: @jjimenez I edited my answer with some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't access data from one controller to another, it's not a good practice. In order to share data between controllers, you should use a `service`.

Here you have [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xesixo/edit?html,js,output) with an example.

Comment: There is no equivalent to $scope ? Because inheritance doesn't seem a bad practice, is it ?

Comment: OK now I understand the spirit. Thanks for your JSBin.